# Does it make sense to use unique pointers in a linked list?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have the following design for a `List` and `Node` class. I don't particularly care about execution efficiency here, so I'm using a recursive function rather than a simple loop.

```
shared_ptr<Node> Node::insert(int value) {
  if (value == this->datavalue) {
    // we have already seen this value: just count
    datacount++;
    return shared_from_this();
  } else if (value < this->datavalue) {
    // insert before current
    auto newhead = shared_ptr<Node>( new Node(value) );
    newhead->next = this->shared_from_this();
    return newhead;
  } else if (next == nullptr) {
    // insert after current, and current is the tail
    this->next = shared_ptr<Node>( new Node(value) );
    return shared_from_this();
  } else {
    // insert after current, which is not the tail
    auto newtail = next->insert(value);
    this->next = newtail;
    return shared_from_this();
  }
};
void List::insert(int value) {
  if (head == nullptr) // list is empty; make first node
    head = shared_ptr<Node>( new Node(value) );
  else // insert this value somewhere
    head = head->insert(value);
};
```

I can not figure out how to use unique pointers here. The `Node::insert` routine returns `shared_from_this` in one case, or a new node in another case. So I would sort of need `unique_from_this`, which I know doesn't exist.

Can I maintain this design, or should I just write a big while loop over the list?

PS I should really use `make_shared` in the above.

Comment: The big problem is your design choice to use recursion and have the `insert` function handled by the `Node` instead of entirely in the `List`. That leads to your current need to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. Instead of thinking about these "smart pointers" as simply self-deleting pointers, think about them in terms of *ownership*. Who *owns* the nodes? Do the nodes own themselves? Do the `List` own the nodes? Can that ownership be shared?

Comment: It can make sense. In a singly linked list the node is a reasonable place to put ownership  of the next node. In a doubly linked list, `next` and `prev` as `unique_ptr`s makes no sense because one node's `next` is another's `prev` and so much for unique. But if you pick one and leave the other raw (or, if you're posh, `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter that does nothing).

Comment: `shared_ptr` makes no sense for a singly linked list because who is the node shared with? No one. In a doubly linked list it looks like it makes sense, `next` and `prev` both point to the same thing, but then you have to consider that the node is either in the list or out of it, so it's not really being shared.

Comment: @user4581301: indeed, so that's why I was trying the replace shared with unique.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: A node owns its next, because maybe I want to transplant that tail onto something else. Clearly the tail is then not owned by anyone but the node that directly points at it. Likewise the list only owns the head node. So there is no shared ownership. I do see that the design of Node::insert is problematic. Maybe I should replace it with a function that can only update the tail. But then I get code replication because that function needs to be both in the Node and List class.

Comment: Why does insert return a node pointer? If you want it unique, then you can't keep it in the list and return it, but what if you return void?

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom : when would inserting a node, given a node, ever return void? I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: Take care when deleting the list when using unique pointers for next.  The delete will go recursive and with a long list may exceed the default stack size

Comment: No. Use raw pointers. Better yet, don't use a linked list.